# _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN syntax is not selecting any tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm looking at the public GitHub events dataset `githubarchive.day.YYYYMMDD` to pull public events that belong to me.

For this I use a simple query like:

```sql
SELECT id, actor.login, type
FROM `githubarchive.day.2*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20200520' AND '20200528'
AND actor.login='ahmetb'
```

This `BETWEEN` clause doesn't seem to be matching any tables according to this message

> Query complete (0.4 sec elapsed, 0 B processed)

If I use a simpler syntax like this it works:

```sql
SELECT id, actor.login, type
FROM `githubarchive.day.202005*`
WHERE actor.login='ahmetb'
```

> Query complete (2.2 sec elapsed, 2.4 GB processed)

However using the wildcard syntax directly in `FROM` is not an option for me as I determine the table suffix dynamically through a query parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is correct version

```
SELECT id, actor.login, type
FROM `githubarchive.day.2*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '0200520' AND '0200528'
AND actor.login='ahmetb'
```

Note: you needed to remove first `2` in dates in below line

```
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '0200520' AND '0200528'
```

Or you might wanted below one

```
SELECT id, actor.login, type
FROM `githubarchive.day.*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20200520' AND '20200528'
AND actor.login='ahmetb'
```

which makes more sense to me

Comment: Got it, totally missed I needed to remove `2`. The reason why `.*` doesn't work is there's a view called `yesterday` in that table, so it errors out with `Views cannot be queried through prefix. First view githubarchive:day.yesterday.`.

Comment: yes. you are right. because of that extra table you should use first version :o)

Comment: Yeah the sad part is that YYYYMMDD comes through a `@DS_START_DATE` parameter, so trimming the first `2` looks silly and cryptic to others. :-/